# Haskell - Boolean RoseTree

Tags: haskell

Hello Haskell community,

Given the usual definition of a Rose Tree:

```
RoseTree a = Node a [RoseTree a]
```

I've been scratching my head over the implementation of this particular function:

```
boolRoseTree :: Blocks -> Blocks -> RoseTree a -> Bool
boolRoseTree blocksA blocksB roseTree
```

Where `Blocks` is simply a `[Int]` that is always contains 6 elements which are greater or equal to 0.
Now the function I wish to implement checks if a certain element of `blocksA` is a certain value and a certain element of `blocksB` is also a certain value, and return `True` if the conditions are met. That is very vague, so allow me to clarify with an example:

`| (blocksA !! 0 == 1 || blocksA !! 0 == 10) && blocksB !! 1 /= 0 = True`

i.e. if the 1st element of `blocksA` is either `1` or `10` and the 2nd element of `blocksB` is not `0`, then return `True`. This I wish to do for all elements of `blocksA`, however each time, the elements increase by `+1`. Through that I mean the next guards would be:

```
| (blocksA !! 1 == 2 || blocksA !! 1 == 11) && blocksB !! 2 /= 0 = True
| (blocksA !! 2 == 3 || blocksA !! 2 == 12) && blocksB !! 3 /= 0 = True
| (blocksA !! 3 == 4 || blocksA !! 3 == 13) && blocksB !! 4 /= 0 = True
| (blocksA !! 4 == 5 || blocksA !! 4 == 14) && blocksB !! 5 /= 0 = True
```

Obviously, I could code this with a long list of guards, going through all `blocksA !! 0`,`blocksA !! 1`,`blocksA !! 2`,`blocksA !! 3`,`blocksA !! 4`,`blocksA !! 5` eventually reaching an `otherwise` statement which returns `False`. However, this could be done significantly more effectively (I think) with a Rose Tree.

I imagine that on the first level of the Rose Tree there would have to be six nodes, 0 to 5, representing the elements of the tree. Each of those nodes would then have to have 2 values, which are the two values I want for `blocksA` at that particular element of the list - but then I would also somehow have to check if the corresponding element of `blocksB` is not zero.

I don't really know even where to start on a problem like this... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question in the hope the question is now syntactically valid. But I still don't see what a rose tree has to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how a Rose tree would work here, but what about this
data structure:

```
checks =
    [ ((0,0), [ (1, 10, 1) , (2, 11, 2) , (3, 12, 3) , (4, 13, 4) , (5, 14, 5) ])
    , ((1,..), [ ... ]
    , ((2,..), [ ... ]
    , ...
    , ((5,..), [ ... ]
    ]
```

Here's how to deconstruct it:

```
[ ( (0,0) [ (1, 10, 1) , (2, 11, 2) , (3, 12, 3) , (4, 13, 4) , (5, 14, 5) ]
     i z     x   y  j     x   y  j     x   y  j     ...
```

Each set of values for **i**, **z**, **x**, **y**, and **j** corresponds to
the guard:

```
| ((a !! i) == x || (a !! i) == y) && (b !! j /= z) = True
```

To perform all of the checks, just use a list comprehension:

```
func :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
func a b = or $ do ((i,z), triples) <- checks
                   (x,y,j) <- triples
                   return $ ((a !! i) == x || (a !! i) == y) && (b !! j /= z)
```

All of the elements of the list are or-ed together. Due to laziness the function will return with True as soon as the first True check is encountered.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem - apologies for the failed syntax. @ErikR - In hindsight, I think I was trying to do something which you could not. Thank you for your help.